# Can we use lex with regular expression variable

Tags: regex, lex

Can I pass a pattern as an argument when I run the file using lex something similar to grep. Iam trying to implement grep using lex.

```
%{
      #include <stdio.h>
      char *pattern;
%}
%%
.*{pattern}.*   printf("%s\n",yytext);
%%
int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  if(argc<3)
  {
    printf("usage:lexgrep pattern filename\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  pattern=argv[1];
  yyin=fopen(argv[2],"r");
  yylex();
  return 0;
}
```

This is what I tried. But it didn't worked out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the pattern(s) that lex recognizes are specified at compile time, not run time.  To interpret patterns at run time, you'll need to build your own state machine on the fly.

Comment: Then what does grep use to find the patterns on the fly?

Comment: I don't know how the original Unix grep worked.  If you're feeling adventurous, you could download the source of a Linux distribution and find out how a Linux grep does it.

Comment: Come to think of it, most compiler textbooks would show you how to code a state machine by hand.